# Converting Postman to Curl windows

Tags: windows, curl, postman

I looked at all previous answers on this subject but just can't get my POST request to work in cURL windows although it works perfectly in PostMan. I exported the code using </> and tried several combinations of export parameters... any help would greatly appreciated!

Here's my cURL code:

```
curl -L -X POST "https://timingserver.net/api/bridge/generic" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "connection: close" -H "content-type: application/json" --data-raw "{
\"username\":\"myusername\",
\"password\":\"mypassword\",
\"event\":\"demo\",
\"checkpoint\":12,
\"detections\":[{\"bib\":100, \"dt\":\"2022-01-12T13:09:23.045\"},
{\"bib\":101, \"dt\":\"2022-01-12T13:09:23.045\"},
{\"bib\":102, \"dt\":\"2022-01-12T13:09:23.045\"},
{\"bib\":199, \"dt\":\"2022-01-12T13:10:23.045\"}]
}"
```

Getting several errors in the same execution: Code 400, not recognized as an internal or external command... cannot find the path specified...

Comment: Are you using CMD or PowerShell? In the latter (like in Unix shells) a `"`-quoted string can contain linebreaks (and thus be multiline), but not the former; there you need to prefix each linebreak that you want treated as data with `^` (hat/caret/uparrow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the linebreaks:

```
curl -L -X POST "https://timingserver.net/api/bridge/generic" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "connection: close" -H "content-type: application/json" --data-raw "{ \"username\":\"myusername\", \"password\":\"mypassword\", \"event\":\"demo\", \"checkpoint\":12, \"detections\":[{\"bib\":100, \"dt\":\"2022-01-12T13:09:23.045\"}, {\"bib\":101, \"dt\":\"2022-01-12T13:09:23.045\"}, {\"bib\":102, \"dt\":\"2022-01-12T13:09:23.045\"}, {\"bib\":199, \"dt\":\"2022-01-12T13:10:23.045\"}] }"
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. I did some more work and created a JSON input file as I will likely send  100s of checkpoint times in the same POST. It simplifies the cURL line quite a bit and got it to work that way. curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://timingserver.net/api/bridge/generic" --data "@results.json"

Comment: Good to hear that. In case my answer solved your initial question: Thanks for accepting the answer and upvoting it.

Comment: Wish I could, I don't have enough "reputations" to cast a vote yet!

Comment: But you can accept the answer

Answer (score 6):

To generate curl output for windows using postman click on settings next to curl code section and change line continuation character to ^ and quote double and shown in the image. This should generate output for windows. You can also change the output to single or multiline.

[image]